# Restore a bak file which is more than 3 GB on a SQL Server 2017 Express edition getting error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, ssms-2017

I am trying to restore database whose size is around 3 GB to a SQL Server 2017 Express edition, but I keep getting this error:

> Msg 1827, Level 16, State 4, Line 11
>   CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The error says it all: the restored size would be more than 10 GB, which is the size limit for SQL Server Express. In brief: you **CANNOT** restore this database to an Express edition - you need a Web, Standard or Enterprise Edition of SQL Server to restore it to ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Express limits the maximum database size to 10GB.

Shrink the database and try.

Comment: After shrinking database size is around 3gb any other alternative solution?